# Sails.js REST Api Validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, rest, sails.js

I'm trying to setup a backend REST API with Sails js. However validation is not working out of the box. Is this the normal behaviour?

I've looked at the [guide](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models) and added validation to my model but still when I use something like POSTMAN on chrome it still creates the record without validation.

How can I ad validation to the REST API?

Comment: What adapter are you using? If it does not require a schema by default, have you set schema:true?

Comment: post your model's code

Comment: It was the schema. @satyrwilder please add it as answer and I'll mark it correct. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What adapter are you using? If it does not require a schema by default, you need to set `schema:true` in the config.

Comment: I was testing it with the disk storage. I added Mongo db and added schema:true. Worked great. Thanks again.